# Which data to use for forecast - Test/Train data

Tags: r, forecasting

I am fairly new to R and I am trying to develop forecast models after the model is selected based on accuracy, do we use the entire historicals for forecasting with the selected model? Or do we use train/test data for the forecast?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a time series not r question. I think the norm is to use all the data to predict the future not the training data set.